# report progress backgroundworker from different class c#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

In my .NET C# project I have used a "BackgroundWorker" to call a method in a different class. The following is the source-code of my main form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        testClass t1 = new testClass();
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            t1.changevalue(1000);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text += Convert.ToString(e.ProgressPercentage);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

and have the following code in a separate class file named "testClass.cs" in my project. I want to report the progress to the BackgroundWorker from this class, so that I will be able to display the progress in the main from label1.

```
class testClass
    {
        private int val;
        public int changevalue(int i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            {
                val += i + j;
                //from here i need to preport the backgroundworker progress
                //eg; backgroundworker1.reportProgress(j);
            }
            return val;
        }
    }
```

but I am not allowed to access BackgroundWorker from the "testClass".

Can someone please tell how to overcome this problem?

p.s- I have found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289920/c-sharp-how-to-report-progress-from-within-a-class-to-a-backgroundworker), but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could just pass it in as a variable

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    t1.changevalue(1000, sender as BackgroundWorker);
}


class testClass
{
    private int val;
    public int changevalue(int i, BackgroundWorker bw)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            val += i + j;
            bw.ReportProgress(i);
            //from here i need to preport the backgroundworker progress
            //eg; backgroundworker1.reportProgress(j);
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

**But** I think the best option would be an `event` in the `testClass` that your `Form` can assign to.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;
    private testClass t1 = new testClass();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // subscribe to your event
        t1.OnProgressUpdate += t1_OnProgressUpdate;
    }

    private void t1_OnProgressUpdate(int value)
    {
        // Its another thread so invoke back to UI thread
        base.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            label1.Text += Convert.ToString(value);
        });
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        t1.changevalue(1000);
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

}

class testClass
{
    public delegate void ProgressUpdate(int value);
    public event ProgressUpdate OnProgressUpdate;

    private int val;
    public int changevalue(int i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            val += i + j;

            // Fire the event
            if (OnProgressUpdate != null)
            {
                OnProgressUpdate(i);
            }
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you so much Mr. @sa_ddam213. This is what exactly I was looking for. Your code works like charm. Cheers!!

Comment: Your second solution looks a little bit more difficult to read. Why do you think it's better than the first?

Comment: @Nolonar , Well, the second version separates the `BackgroundWorker` from the logic class, not only that the class can now return progress regardless of it being used with a `BacgroundWorker` or not, you just need to subscribe to the 'OnProgressUpdate' event and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this same issue (my long running process is a database restore), and solved it in a similar way by raising an event in the other class, but then had my subscriber to that event just act as a wrapper to backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress().

```
private void DBRestoreProgressHandler(DataAccess da, DataAccess.DatabaseRestoreEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(e.RestoreProgress);
    }

private void backgroundWorker1_ReportProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        someLabel.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }
```

This saved having to use:

```
base.Invoke((Action)delegate
```

Which I think can then cause problems if the form closes unexpectedly?

Answer (score -2):

Am i missing this in the above code ?:

backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);

Comment: I am not sur this qualifies as an answer. Don't you think?