# Using Events to update UI from a backgroundworker with another class

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, class, backgroundworker

I’m trying to use events to update a textbox from a background worker from a different class.

It is the same problem as mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871238/report-progress-backgroundworker-from-different-class-c-sharp), except I'm using VB.NET.  I'm trying to implement the 2nd suggested solution by @sa_ddam213.

I’m getting an error: “Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'txtResult' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.”

Here is my code:

```
Public Class DataProcessor
    Public Delegate Sub ProgressUpdate(ByVal value As String)
    Public Event OnProgressUpdate As ProgressUpdate

    Private Sub PushStatusToUser(ByVal status As String)
        RaiseEvent OnProgressUpdate(status)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ProcessAllFiles(ByVal userData As UserData)
        'Do the work
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MainForm
    Private bw As New BackgroundWorker
    Private dp As New DataProcessor

    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

        If bw.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
        Else
            dp.ProcessAllFiles(CType(e.Argument, UserData))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub dp_OnProgressUpdate(ByVal status As String)
        txtResult.Text = status
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted

        AddHandler dp.OnProgressUpdate, AddressOf dp_OnProgressUpdate
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks all!

Comment: You have a Class running on a BGW from inside a form. Instead of trying to bubble information all the way from the bottom to the top, if the DP Class created and ran the BGW, it could catch the Progress reports and Completed events and simply report them to the Form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event still comes from a different thread than the UI. You need to delegate the woke back to the UI. I don't check `InvokeRequired` because I know it is from the worker thread.

`Me` is the form, [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) asks for the delegate that will handle the work of bring the data to the UI thread. Here my Delegate `Sub` is a lambda Sub instead of using a normal Sub routine - simpler design.

```
Private Sub dp_OnProgressUpdate(ByVal status As String)
   'invoke the UI thread to access the control
   'this is a lambda sub
   Me.Invoke(Sub
               'safe to access the form or controls in here
               txtResult.Text = status
             End Sub)
 End Sub
```

Comment: That works thank you.  Extra credit, can you explain this further?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try doing something like this?

```
    Private Delegate Sub del_Update(ByVal status As String)

    Private Sub dp_OnProgressUpdate(ByVal status As String)
        If txtResult.InvokeRequired Then
            txtResult.Invoke(New del_Update(AddressOf dp_OnProgressUpdate),  New Object() {status})
        Else
            target_textbox.text = status 
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that is the old delegate way to do it. Lot more code to do the same thing - don't you think?