# Fill DataGridView in a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

i have a DataGridView that i want to fill with data, the data that will be in the DataGridView are generated dynamically, there's no datable to use as binding, i use a loop and fill each row of the DataGridView on each iteration.

```
   private void Historique()
    {
        int k = 0;
        for(int i= this.start_his; i <= this.end_his; i++)
        {
            DGV.Rows.Add();
            DGV.Rows[k].Cells[0].Value = "semaine " + i;
            DGV.Rows[k].Cells[1].Value = TOOLS.GetMaxHebdo(this.annee_his, 
            i);
            k++;
        }

    }
```

the function

```
 TOOLS.GetMaxHebdo(this.annee_his, i);
```

take a while to respond, so i want to fill each row of the DataGridView without blocking the program and see the rows displaying one by one, is there a way to do that using a thread or something ?

Comment: Are you saying you want the grid to fill with all rows up to "end_his"... but each row will have a blank Cells[1].value until the data is returned GetMaxHebdo?!

Comment: @Wheels73 thanks for your answer, yes i want that the row is shown when the data is ready

Comment: That's what i was thinking. But if you only want to show the row when the data is ready, why do you need another thread?

Comment: because the interval between start_his and end_his can be bigger, and when it's a big interval, the DGV can take more than 2 minutes to display, in other case visual studio stopped the execution, so i wanted a way to display  the row one by one until the treatement finishes, and avoid waiting and (bloking) the program for a long time to display the DGV

Comment: There is....Just not the first answers way. I'd look at the invoke method of the control or the Background worker class. This is ideal for having a process run the in the background which raises and event to the main thread allowing you to update your grid. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475673/using-events-to-update-ui-from-a-backgroundworker-with-another-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Exactly this scenario is one of fundamental usages for async/await pattern.

1. Add `using System.Threading.Tasks;` at the top.
2. mark your method async: `private async void Historique()`
3. Call the slow method as task: `DGV.Rows[k].Cells[1].Value = await Task.Run(()=>TOOLS.GetMaxHebdo(this.annee_his, i));`

Comment: thank you, this is what i was looking for, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the load function in it's own thread and run the thread in the background into a hidden dataGridView, so when the program is started the data is already loading in the background and saved as a dataTable to be used whenever you want 
I doubt many people would be too averse to a splashscreen with a loading bar on program start :)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

This may help you. Call your function through a thread to avoid blocking the Main thread and your program.

```
Thread1 = new System.Threading.Thread(Historique);
Thread1.Start();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it generates an exception saying that DGV is acceced from another thread

Comment: You can not update windows forms from anything other than the main UI thread as its not thread safe.

Comment: Okay so there's not an other way