# Run background workers sequentially

Tags: c#, winforms

I've built a C# Winforms app that serves as a simulation to run a set of tasks that are computationally and memory intensive.  I'm using a background worker to do the work so the UI can remain responsive.  I've got just a for loop:

```
var iterations = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumIterations.Text);
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
ResetSim();
StartWorker("RunSimulation", i + 1);
}
```

What I would like is to just run these sequentially in the background, but I can't figure out if a background worker set up will do this, or if I need to use Tasks.  I haven't found a really good example that explains how a Task could accomplish my goal. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use one worker and put the `for` loop inside of it?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, that's what exactly I would do. I feel, you should post that as answer cause that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run your simulations sequentially then you can subscribe to the background workers [`RunWorkerCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event to start the next one.

So you just start the first worker off:

```
var worker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
worker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
worker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Then in the handler:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var worker2 = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker2.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker2.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Obviously you can use an array to hold the references to each worker and have a class variable to hold which one's active. You'd then only need one handler to increment the simulation count and start the next one in the list.

Comment: Then what's the point of using BackGroundWorker at all. Why not just run all the method/actions in classic synchronous fashion.

Comment: @Rahul  - well you might want the UI to be responsive while processing so you can do other tasks, cancel the simulation etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4(v=vs.110).aspx) in the DoWork method in order to pass back information to the main thread. You could do the loop in the DoWork method and at each loop call `worker.ReportProgress(i);` with the loop variable. The value is not interpreted by the background worker, so it needs not to be a percentage value. Then in the [ProgressChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3289920/880990) event handler you can call `ResetSim();`. (I assume that `ResetSim` acts in the UI and must therefore be executed on the UI thread.)

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you really don't need multiple background workers, just use a single background worker and run the loop inside of it.